# how to wait until the required window title appers in pywinauto

Tags: python

How to wait until the required window title to be appers using **pywinauto**?

I have to wait for required window title, once I found that window title have to do some action on that window. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `pywinauto.timings.WaitUntilPasses`

```
app = pywinauto.Application()
app.start('calc')
window = pywinauto.timings.WaitUntilPasses(10, 0.5, lambda: app.window_(title=u'About Calculator'))
#run About manually in 10 seconds
<pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x02DD0DB0>
```

Comment: >>Thank you for the reply. But in the above method we need to mention the seconds like   for how much seconds it as to wait for the window title, but I dont want to give the time so that it as to wait for those many seconds. In autoIt we have WinWait method where this method waits until the window title appers. So is there any same kind of method is available in pywinauto?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you are looking for. 10 seconds - the maximum time that we are willing to wait window.
Execution will end as soon as the window will be found (if less than 10 seconds), or raises an exception - Timeout (if the window does not appear for 10 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Ok now i got how to use `WaitUntilPasses` this method I was trying below small script.

```
app = pywinauto.Application() 
app.start('Notepad') 
Win = "Untitled1.txt" + "-" + "Notepad" 
window = pywinauto.timings.WaitUntilPasses(20, 0.5, lambda: app.window_(title=Win))
app.Untitled1.MenuSelect('Help -> About Notepad')
```

Here after opening the notepad within 20sec i saved the notepad with `Untitled1.txt` and after saving the notpad title of the notepad shown like `"Untitled1.txt - Notepad"` So in the above script am waiting for the same title and once i got the same title trying to select the menu option in that notepad but after 20sec am getting here am getting timeout error.

Comment: I got the solution i used below code it worked.  app = pywinauto.application.Application()   app.Start('Notepad')  Win = "Untitled.txt" + " " + "-" + " " + "Notepad" window = pywinauto.timings.WaitUntilPasses(20, 0.5, lambda: app.window_(title=Win)) window.MenuSelect('Help -> About Notepad')